# Redirect only blog posts, not directory in .htacess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a webpage with a blog at www.example.com/blog, but the permalink structure is www.example.com/blog-post-url. I have blog posts linked from around the web from years ago with a different permalink structure which is www.example.com/blog/blog-post-url.

So what I need to do is redirect all old blog links from /blog/blog-post-url to just /blog-post-url but without actually redirecting the /blog directory (the blog home page url) to the root /.

Comment: Did you mean, you want to redirect a post to another url or page? Why not try a plugin instead? https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Comment: Well, technically the posts don't even exists at /blog/blog-post/, but they did years ago, and back links still exist.

So I want to redirect:

example.com/blog/happy-days --->  example.com/happy-days

But while maintaining the home page URL:

example.com/blog/ ---> example.com/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I think I placed it in the wrong place, it seems to be working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try to use .htaccess but checking if uri is /blog/blog* and if it is, then just redirect it to /blog*
So it should be something like `RewriteRule ^/blogs/(.*)$ /$1` or something similar.

Comment: I tried adding 'RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1', but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Very close, I found the solution - thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect all non-existence folder a.k.a blog posts to a new place (from /blog/blog-posts --> /blog-posts) while not redirecting the existing files and directories inside the /blog folder.

Going to /blog/existing_directories will not redirect to /existing_directories

Put the .htaccess file on the root directory, and that shall only redirect blog posts to the new link.

Hope that helps.

Comment: IT ending up working, except it still redirecting /blog/ to the main root /. Thanks for your help!